# Are floating point SMT logics slower than real ones?

Tags: haskell, z3, smt, sbv

I wrote an application in Haskell that calls Z3 solver to solve constrains with some complex formulas. Thanks to Haskell I can quickly switch the data type I'm working with.

When using SBV's `AlgReal` type for computations, I get results in sensible time, however switching to `Float` or `Double` types makes Z3 consume ~2Gb of RAM and doesn't result even in 30 minutes.

Is this expected that producing floating point solutions require much more time, or it is some mistake on my side?

Comment: I'm only half an expert, but I believe that yes, the theory of IEEE754 is *significantly* more complicated than the theory of arbitrary algebraic reals because every operation includes a rounding operation that is quite difficult to reason about. (Not writing this as an answer because I'm only half an expert and only about 80% trust my own statement.)

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Ha-ha, to be honest, if SO allowed CC'ing concrete users, I'd just added @ LeventErkok into the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As with any question regarding solver performance, it is impossible to make generalizations. Christoph Wintersteiger (https://stackoverflow.com/users/869966/christoph-wintersteiger) would be the expert on this to opine, but I'm not sure how closely he follows this group. Chris: If you're reading this, I'd love to hear your thoughts!

There's also the risk of comparing apples-to-oranges here: Reals and floats are two completely different logics, with different decision procedures, heuristics, algorithms, etc. I'm sure you can find problems where one outperforms the other, with no clear "performance" winner.

Having said all that, here are some things that make floating-point (FP) tricky:

- Rewriting is almost impossible with FP, since rules like associativity simply 
  don't hold for FP addition/multiplication. So, there are fewer opportunities for 
  simplification before bit-blasting.
- Similarly `a * 1/a == 1` doesn't hold for floats. Neither does `x + 1 /= x` or `(x + a == x) -> (a == 0)` and many other "obvious" simplifications that you'd love to be able to make. All of this complicates reasoning.
- Existence of `NaN` values make equality non-reflexive: Nothing compares equal to `NaN` including itself. So, substitution of equals-for-equals is also problematic and requires side conditions.
- Likewise, the existence of `+0` and `-0`, which compare equal but behave differently due to rounding complicate matters. The typical example is `x == 0 -> fma(a, b, x) == a * b` doesn't hold (where `fma` is fused multiply-add), because depending on the sign of zero these two expressions can produce different values for different rounding modes.
- Combination of floats with integers and reals introduce non-linearity, which is always a soft-spot for solvers. So, if you're using FP, it is advisable not to mix it with other theories as the combination itself creates extra complexity.
- Operations like multiplication, division, and remainder (yes, there's a floating-point remainder operation!) are inherently very complex and lead to extremely large SAT formulas. In particular, multiplication is a known operation that challenges most SAT/BDD engines, due to lack of any good variable ordering and splitting heuristics. Solvers end-up bit-blasting fairly quickly, resulting in extremely large state-spaces. I have observed that solvers have a hard time dealing with FP division and remainder operations even when the input is completely concrete, imagine what happens when they are fully symbolic!
- The logic of reals have a decision procedure with a double-exponential complexity. However, techniques like Fourier-Motzkin elimination (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination), while remaining exponential, perform really well in practice.
- FP solvers are relatively new, and it's a niche area with nascent research. So existing solvers tend to be quite conservative and quickly bit-blast and reduce the problem to bit-vector logic. I would expect them to improve over time, just like all the other theories did.

Again, I want to emphasize comparing solver performance on these two different logics is misguided as they are totally different beasts. But hopefully, the above points illustrate why floating-point is tricky in practice.

A great paper to read about the treatment of IEEE754 floats in SMT solvers is: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/BTRW14.pdf. You can see the myriad of operations it supports and get a sense of the complexity.

Comment: Yep, all of what @levent-erkok said. Note that replacing reals with floats/doubles does not preserve any semantics of the problem or the properties, i.e., this is unsound. Regarding performance: imagine translating a trivial, completely linear problem on reals where we replace the reals with floats. The result is a highly non-linear and discontinuous problem for which none of the "nice" methods on reals work and even where there are similar methods, they have much higher complexity.